# JavaFX16: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @...'

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-shade-plugin, openjfx, java-16

I have a Maven multi-module project on IntelliJ that produces 3 jars, 2 of which are executables and the other one is for commmon resources.

One of the executable modules has a main class that asks if the user wants to start the program with CLI or GUI.

Running this main from IntelliJ works without problem, instead when I use Maven to make the jar (using maven shade):

```
mvn package -pl myModule -am
```

and then launch the jar with GUI option, this warning appears:

```
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @...'
```

The GUI then starts without problems.

**How can I get rid of this warning?**
The JDK of my project is openJDK 16 (I've already added `module-info.java` in order to work with javafx), openJFX 16, maven shade plugin 3.2.4, maven compiler plugin 3.8.1.

If there's need to add furthermore information, I'll add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that maven is shading the JavaFX jars into a single fat jar.

Shading multiple modules into the same jar is not possible, because a jar can only contain 1 module. So, I suppose the shade plugin resolves that problem by removing the module-info files of the dependencies it's using, which means the JavaFX code will not be loaded as a module, and you get a warning like this.

I think the only way to get rid of the warning is to not use shading, but keep the JavaFX modules as separate jar files, that you then put on the module path when running the application.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response.
I need shading because otherwise I would not be able to include the "common resources" module into the jar and so it wouldn't work (ClassNotFoundException).
At least, I think it's necessary to do this in this way, but I don't really know.

Comment: @cathartyc I don't know about your project structure, but it looks like you can manually list includes for the shade plugin as well: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html So, I think you should be able to only include the common resources module in the shading process.

Comment: I managed to make the jar without JavaFX, but now I don't have any idea how to run the jar. JavaFX modules are controlled by Maven, how can I find them?
And this project is shared with 2 other people, so I'd prefer not to use absolute paths. How can I do that?

Comment: @cathartyc You can copy the dependencies to the build directory using `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, and then you should be able to run the program with something like `java -jar <main jar> -p <path to JavaFX jars folder>`. Long term, you might want to look into using `jpackage` to create a distribution of the app. `jpackage` can create a bundle with a JVM/runtime and an executable launcher as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot use jpackage for this work, but I managed to make things work using the `java -p <path/to/JavaFX/jars/folder> --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar myJar.jar` command (actually I made a batch in the jar folder).